# C output not as expected - Global variable returns different value

Tags: c, global-variables

I'm trying to read from a file and load some sort of word count into a 2d array as occ_table which is declared as a global variable. I wrote a OCC_print function to print the result in that array.

But the code is not behaving as I expected. In the readbychunks() function, occ_prints every iteration of that 2d array correctly. But when I do a final print in main, the first column numbers are different.

My apologies for the messy code, below attaching the code `test.c` and file to be read `test.bwt`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int BUFFER_SIZE =30;
int c_SIZE = 96;
int c[96];
int GAP = 5;
int occ_height = 1;
int cLen =0;
int sLen = 0;
int** occ_table;

// max len of c list is 96 : ASCII 10 + 32-126 as given
//inputs a char ASCII # outputs i location in c[96]
int c_charEncoder(int ascii){
    if(ascii == 10){return 0;}
    else{ return ascii-32-1; }
}
int c_charDecoder(int c_location){
    if(c_location==0){return 10;}
    else{return c_location+32+1;}
}
//initiate occ table with allocated memories and initial values
void initiate_occ(){
    for (int i = 0; i< c_SIZE+1; i++)
    {
        occ_table[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(occ_height+1));
        for(int j = 0; j <= occ_height+1; j++){occ_table[i][j] = 0;}
    }
    // return occ_table;
}

//print OCC
void print_OCC(){
    //printf("OCC to be loaded \n\n");
    for ( int r = 0; r <occ_height; r++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < c_SIZE; i++)
        {   
            printf("%d ",occ_table[i][r]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }  
}
void readbychunks(){
    int ctr = 0; // count how many chars in file read - if ctr -1 = row number
    FILE *fp = fopen("test.bwt", "r");
    if (fp != NULL) {
        /* Go to the end of the file. */
        if (fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END) == 0) {
            /* Get the size of the file. */
            sLen = ftell(fp);

            /* Allocate our buffer to that size. */
            char* source = malloc(sizeof(char) * (sLen/BUFFER_SIZE + 1));
            int occ_accumulator[96];
            for(int o=0;o<c_SIZE; o++){occ_accumulator[o]=0;}

            occ_height = sLen/GAP+1;
            initiate_occ();
            print_OCC();
            printf("occ height is %d length is %d \n\n",occ_height,c_SIZE);
            /* Go back to the start of the file. */
            fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);

            /* Read the entire file into memory by chunks */
            for(int i=0; i<sLen/BUFFER_SIZE+1;i++){
                int blockLen = fread(source, sizeof(char), BUFFER_SIZE, fp);
                
                for (int j = 0; j < blockLen; j++)
                {   
                    ctr ++;
                    char token= source[j];
                    int c_location = c_charEncoder(token);
                        printf("Token is %c \n C updated to:\n",token);
                    // increase c by 1
                    c[c_location]++;
                        // for (int x = 0; x < c_SIZE; x++){printf("%d ",c[x]);}
                    // increase occ_accumulator by 1
                        // printf("\nOCC new row is :\n");
                    occ_accumulator[c_location]++;
                        // for (int x = 0; x < c_SIZE; x++){printf("%d ",occ_accumulator[x]);}
                    // only push to occ_table with GAPs
                    if ((ctr-1)%GAP == 0){
                        int row = (ctr-1)/GAP;
                        printf("%d row current ctr is %d\n",row,ctr-1);
                            // for (int x = 0; x < c_SIZE; x++){printf("%d ",occ_accumulator[x]);}
                            // printf("\n");


                        for(int c=0; c<c_SIZE; c++){occ_table[c][row] = occ_accumulator[c];}
                            // for (int x = 0; x < c_SIZE; x++){printf(" accum table has %d, occ has %d\n ", occ_accumulator[x],occ_table[x][row]);}

                            print_OCC();
                            printf("\n");
                    }
                        // printf("%c has ascii %d should be in %d in c has decoded ASCII %d\n",source[j],source[j],c_charEncoder(source[j]),c_charDecoder(c_charEncoder(source[j])));

                }
            printf("%s",source);  
            memset(source,'\0',BUFFER_SIZE); // reset the buffer
            }
        
  
            //free(source);
            fclose(fp);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    occ_table = (int**)malloc(c_SIZE*sizeof(int*));
    readbychunks();
    printf("final OCC table is :\n");
    print_OCC();
    // printf("\n\n\n%d",occ_table[0][0]);
}
```

The code reads this file `test.bwt`:

```
ipssm
pissii
```

result I got:

[as you can see two tables printed should be the same, but the final one has column 1 all 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feLYy.png)

Comment: Not sure if its the entire cause, but your `char* source = malloc(sizeof(char) * (sLen/BUFFER_SIZE + 1));` line looks very odd, when you later use `source` as a buffer of size `BUFFER_LENGTH` in `int blockLen = fread(source, sizeof(char), BUFFER_SIZE, fp);`.

Comment: At least you’re going out of bounds in your loop in `initiate_occ` which won’t help

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the output **as text** and format it as a code block instead of showing a screenshot. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: And what is the *goal* of this program?